# How to move files over samba share with gnomevfs cli

Tags: command-line, samba, cron, gnomevfs

Ok I am in the process of backing up my film collection to a NAS and I wanted to automate this as much as possible as I have to work at the same time. I am trying to setup a daily dump of ISO's ready to be converted overnight. I would like to do this as a cron job using gnomevfs. I have been able to connect and do an ls command successfully with

`gnomevfs-ls smb://user:WORKGROUP:password@media-centre/videos/`

but I am having trouble setting up a mv command from a local folder to the same shared folder keep getting the `Usage: gnomevfs-mv <from> <to>` quote which isn't particularly informative ;)

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gnomevfs is deprecated, you should use gvfs instead.

To move a file :

```
gvfs-mount smb://user:WORKGROUP:password@server/directory
gvfs-move file smb://server/directory/file
```

Comment: is there any way to do this for multiple files of a single type eg *.txt or *.iso etc

Comment: This is not working for me. When I use the gvfs-mount line, it still prompts for Domain and Password. And then no matter what I enter, it doesn't accept it.